# Knockout Bind after Creation

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So a simple view:

```
<div data-bind="with: viewModel">
    <h1 data-bind="text: someproperty"></h1>

    <button data-bind="click: createNewButton">Create new Button</button>

    <div data-bind="foreach: buttons">
        <div data-bind="html: button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.someproperty = ko.observable("hi");

    self.buttons = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.createNewButton = function () {
        self.buttons.push("<button data-bind='click: doThis'></button>");
    }

    self.doThis = function () {
        console.log(this);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings({viewModel: new viewModel()});
```

So effectively, once the button has been added to the observable and the view updated, I would want to re-apply bindings. Is this possible?

Comment: You set to the for each a button property, but I don't see that property in the model. And can you be more specific on what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Its alright, someone answered exactly what I wanted to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd be better off using templates to solve this, like so:

```
<script type="text/html" id="btnTemplate'>
    <button data-bind='click: $root.doThis'></button>
</script>

<div data-bind="with: viewModel">
    <h1 data-bind="text: someproperty"></h1>

    <button data-bind="click: createNewButton">Create new Button</button>

    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'btnTemplate', foreach: buttons }">
    </div>
</div>
```

Template engine will handle binding descendents automatically.

If you really *must* bind the children after rendering, you'd want to write a callback in your foreach afterRender:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: buttons, afterRender: bindNode }">
</div>

self.bindNode = function(elements, data) {
    var element = $(elements).filter('div');
    ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element[0], 
       { 
           click: function() { return self.someAction } //Needs to be wrapped in a function call
       } );
}
```

check out this JS Fiddle for a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/34D6J/

I VERY STRONGLY recommend doing it either through a template, like the first example, or through a custom binding of some sort, otherwise you'll have issues maintaining context and other stuff.

Comment: that is pretty smart!! So with the templating I dont need any extra libraries such as tmpl?

Comment: all so, does the current context get passed through to the click, so if this was in a table and you wanted the current item (`$data`) sent through to the click to be dealt with, is this possible?

Comment: @No1_Melman no, you don't need any extra libraries, knockout supports that templating  innately. If you use templating, and not the hack that I posted second, a click binding event will pass the context as the first parameter. Like so: function(datacontext, event) { //access datacontext here }